# How can I build a dll with cgo and .def file

Tags: go

I want to implement dll forwarding(or dll proxy)

In mingw, I can use cpp source with .def file, like `gcc -shared -o test.dll functions.def test.cpp`

But I don't know how to implement it in golang

Answer (score 1):

I know what to do to solve this problem.

use the extldflags

### First Way:

1. compile the .def file to .exp file

```
dlltool --def functions.def --output-exp evildll.exp
```

2. compile main.go

main.go

```
package main

import "C"

func main() {
    // Need a main function to make CGO compile package as C shared library
}
```

use command `go build -buildmode=c-shared -o exportgo.dll -ldflags="-extldflags=-Wl,C:/Users/Akkuman/Desktop/go-dll-proxy/evildll.exp"`

then you can get the dll

[image: click me to view image]

### Second Way

use command `go build -buildmode=c-shared -o exportgo.dll -ldflags="-extldflags=-Wl,C:/Users/Akkuman/Desktop/go-dll-proxy/functions.def"`

then you can get the dll, but with a additional export function

[image: click me to view image]